# python - importing array into pandas but losing a column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
 import Numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import sklearn
 from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

 Boston1 = load_boston()
 Boston2 = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names[0:13])
 Boston2.keys()
```

the MEDV column disappears? Please help this is driving me crazy and I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets as DS

boston1 = DS.load_boston()
boston2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([boston1.data, boston1.target]), 
    columns=np.r_[boston1.feature_names, ['MEDV']])
print(boston2.keys())
```

yields

```
Index([u'CRIM', u'ZN', u'INDUS', u'CHAS', u'NOX', u'RM', u'AGE', u'DIS', u'RAD',
       u'TAX', u'PTRATIO', u'B', u'LSTAT', u'MEDV'], dtype='object')
```

`print(Boston1.DESCR)` gives the slightly mysterious comment,  "Median Value (attribute 14) is usually the target". But it does not mention how to access the MEDV data.

[The code on this page](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/profjsb/python-seminar/blob/master/DataFiles_and_Notebooks/05_Scikits_Learn/basic_sklearn.ipynb) shows the way: `boston1.target` is MEDV. I found the page by googling "Boston Medv target".

Comment: Old thread, I know, but your code original code produces the error: `Shape of passed values is (14, 506), indices imply (13, 506)`

Comment: @DanHoynoski: Thanks for the bug report. It appears `boston1.feature_names` no longer includes `MEDV`. So `MEDV` has to be added to the value passed to the `columns` parameter: e.g. `np.r_[boston1.feature_names, ['MEDV']]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: boston1.feature_names
Out[9]: 
array(['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD',
       'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

It's not in the feature_names, so it's not loaded.

Comment: sorry, can you please provide more detail?  I'm used to do this sort of work in R where it is more intuitive to me.  Can you explain how I can fix this?

Comment: @user3788557 It doesn't appear that the MEDV column is there to begin with. I believe it might be stored in boston1.target, but I'm not sure.